# Angular 2 Polymer Vaadin combo-box set value programatically

Tags: angular, combobox, polymer, vaadin

```
<vaadin-combo-box
             [items]="myValues"
             item-label-path="code"
             item-value-path="code"
             allow-custom-value="true"
></vaadin-combo-box>
```

I have a vaadin-combox-box element with a list of objects:

```
[ {code:'x', name:'y} ]
```

I want that when a user selects a value from the list, the displayed value to be the selected value + a suffix (eg: user selects value "apples" from drop down list and the displayed value is "apples-test".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a custom item template to show other values in the dropdown than what is the actual label value shown in the input: https://cdn.vaadin.com/vaadin-core-elements/master/vaadin-combo-box/demo/item-template.html